# Как правильно копировать строчки из df при выполнении условия?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм нужно скопировать данные из нее, так чтобы выполнялось условие. Первое это если значение строки в столбе равно 0, или если число остальных строчек не больше определенного числа.
Как это можно сделать, знаю что можно задать первое условие с помощью where, но как туда можно добавить второе условие не понимаю.

Comment: Что такое "остальные строчки"? Сформулируйте чётче. Это все остальные строки датафрейма, не удовлетворяющие условию "значение строки в столбе равно 0" или что имеется в виду? И лучше бы примерами проиллюстрировать прямо в вопросе.

Comment: @CrazyElf - столбец датафрейма [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]. Все что не равняется 0 я назвал остальными строчками столбца. Их нужно копировать, пока значения не будут больше определенного числа.

Comment: помещайте код в таких случаях.  В идеале, с комментариями. И понимать проще, и видно, что автор действительно решает задачу, а не домашнее задание просит ему решить:-)

Comment: @Сергей, ну могу ссылку на репозиторий скинуть в котором несколько тысяч строчек. Не особо понимаю, что тут прикреплять в качестве кода, ну максиму строчку загрузки датафрейма.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решил таким образом, не знаю насколько это хорошее решение.
Скопировал, нужные мне данные с разными условиями в разные датафреймы, а потом для выполнения второго условия удалил строки индекс, которых больше заданного диапозона.
И объединил все в один датафрейм.

Код:

```
test_df = pd.read_csv('DICT_FOR_LEARN (2).csv', sep=';')
test_df_2=test_df.loc[test_df['markup']==0]
test_df_3=test_df.loc[test_df['markup']!=0]
test_df_3.drop(labels=range(test_df['markup'].value_counts()[0], test_df_3.shape[0]) , axis = 0, inplace = True)
final_df = pd.concat([test_df_2, test_df_3]).sample(frac=1)
final_df['markup'].value_counts()
```